# Why am I getting "Invalid Element" on my React code ? Imports are OK

Tags: reactjs

Thank you for reviewing this.

I'm building a React app and suddenly I started getting this error on my App.jsx file:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
> likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
> or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

App.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import UsersList from "./components/UsersList";
import AddUser from "./components/AddUser";
import About from "./components/About";
import axios from "axios";


const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({username: '', email: '', password: ''});
  

  const getUsers = () => {
    axios.get("http://localhost/users").then((res) => {
      setUsers(res.data.data.users) }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err); });
  }

  const addUser = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      username: newUser.username,
      email: newUser.email
    };
    
    axios.post('http://localhost/users', data).then((res) => {console.log(res); }).catch((err) => {console.log(err); });
    setNewUser({username: '', email: ''});
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, [users]);

  return (
    <>
    <section className="section">
    <div className="container">
    <div className="columns">
    <div className="column is-half">
    <br/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
        <>
        <h1 className="title is-1">
        All Users
        </h1>
      <hr/><br/>
      <AddUser addUser={addUser} newUser={newUser} setNewUser={setNewUser} />
      <br/><br/>
      <UsersList users={users} />
      </>
      )} />
      <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section>
    </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

All the components (UsersList, AddUser, About) are exported out using default exports.

Assuming exports and imports are OK, what else I should check to troubleshoot this ?

**edit:**

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.16.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to check the dependencies and React version once.

Comment: So it error went away replaced by `Parsing error: [BABEL] /usr/src/app/src/index.js: Cannot find module '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object'`

Comment: The module is listed in dev dependencies and yet it throws the parsing error.